# How to make Ag-Grid cell text (not entire cell) have a click event

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm trying to open a component whenever the user clicks on the text within a specific cell (in this case in the Name column). The problem I'm running into is that there isn't any method (as far as I can tell) in the Ag-Grid that allows for this. I believe there is a method for adding a click event for the specific cell, but I'm trying to only have it capture the events for when the cell text is clicked. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

I've tried many Ag-Grid methods, but none have cell text click event.

```
this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([{
    headerName: "Name",
    field: "Name"
  },
  {
    headerName: "Description",
    field: "Description"
  },
  {
    headerName: "Actions",
    cellRendererFramework: ActionsRoleComponent,
    autoHeight: false,
    cellClass: 'actions-button-cell d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center',
    width: 80,
    pinned: 'right',
    suppressResize: true,
    suppressFilter: true,
    suppressSorting: true,
    suppressMovable: true,
    cellEditorFramework: ActionsRoleComponent
  }
]);
this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(receivedJson);
this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
```

Comment: Does the click event apply to all cells within the Name column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to customising the cell renderers for ag-Grid, you will need to make use of the [Cell Renderer Componenta](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#angular-cell-render-components).

First, on your component.html, include the input binding for `frameworkComponents`

```
<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    .
    .
  ></ag-grid-angular>
```

On your main component that is using and generating the ag-grid, you will need to import your custom cell component, define the property for `frameworkComponents`, followed by providing the value for `cellRenderer` for the particular column in your column definitions:

```
import { NameRenderer } from "./name-renderer.component";

this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Name",
    field: "name",
    cellRenderer: "nameRenderer",
  },
  // other columns
]

this.frameworkComponents = {
  nameRenderer: NameRenderer,
};
```

And on your custom cell renderer component, `NameRenderer`, you bind the `click` event. I am not sure which part of the cell you would require it to be clickable, but I assume you want the entire `name` to handle the click event

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ICellRendererAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'name-cell',
  template: `<span (click)="onClick($event)">{{ params.value }}</span>`
})

export class NameRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

  // other parts of the component

  onClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
    // handle the rest
  }

}
```

Do not forget to include the custom cell renderer components in your module.ts,

```
import { NameRenderer } from "./name-renderer.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents([NameRenderer])
    // other imported stuff
  ],
  declarations: [
    NameRenderer,
    // other components
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I have forked and created a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JbJ1h9GJahjhfxWF1dvg?p=preview) from the official ag-grid demo. You may refer to cube-renderer.component.ts for the handling of the click event.